# How to convert jpeg image to base64 encoded binary value?

Tags: android, base64

In my android application, i want to convert a **jpeg image to base64 binary encoded value**.
How to acheive this in android ?

**Edit**
I have encoded my bitmap image into  base64 string by following code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream);
            byte[] val = stream.toByteArray();
            String ba = Base64.encodeToString(val, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

The output is in the form of string. BUt I need the output as binary value.

Comment: Are u sending this image to web service ??

Comment: @MohitSharma ya i want to send it to web service.

Answer (score 0):

if using KSOAP2 for connectivity use this 
`new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);` this is do the magic.

Comment: am just sending through post method to a php

Comment: Is input type of your web service is something like this ... base64Binary ?